# 404 error - The requested URL/< was not found on this server. why?

Tags: php, html, forms

I've just finished setting up AMP on a new MacOS El Capitan installation. I don't know why but every time I try to run a simple HTML form with some PHP processing I get a 404 error. I've tried it with the default MacOS document root, I've also tried with the user-level document root, and I've even installed MAMP as a last-resort move. In all these setups the result is always the same when I hit the submit button: 404.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$post = $_POST['post'];
$link = $_POST['link']; 
echo $name; 
echo $post; 
echo $link; 
echo "all good";
} 
?>

<form name="upload" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
   Name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   Post:<br>
   <input type="text" name="post"><br>
   Link:<br>
   <input type="text" name="link"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```

The error is "The requested URL/< was not found on this server."

What am I missing??

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you inspected the resulting html for the form? It seems the value of action is `<`. Have you verified that php is parsing your script at all? `<?php die('Hello world'); ?>`

Comment: I don't see any issue, I can get the output from the form. Are you trying locally?

Comment: Yes, I am trying locally. I can run a php file with the die command in Aron's reply without any problems but if I insert the same die command into my php code above (and delete all the other lines of code within that if clause) I get the 404 error!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the action for your form isn't parsing correctly. Your code runs fine on my server as it is - however, every server is different.
You could try moving the double quotes inside the php section to see if that's tripping up the parser somehow:

Change

```
 <form name="upload" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
```

to

```
<form name="upload" action=<?php echo "\"".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."\""; ?> method="post">
```

or alternatively

```
<form name="upload" action=<?php echo "'".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."'"; ?> method="post">
```

In theory all of these should result in the same thing - but it's worth a try.

Comment: What's the html of the form on your server, specifically what's the action attribute turning out as?

Comment: I've now made it as simple as possible with a "die('Hello world');" and the result is still that 404.
My real script inserts the text introduced in the textboxes in a SQL database.

Comment: Does it work with action="" (i.e. blank action attribute) - that normally sends the form back to the same script?

Comment: With action="" I don't get the 404, it reloads the form

Comment: Feels like the php is not being processed properly. Try it on a web server perhaps?

Comment: that must be it but I don't understand why...I followed all the steps to install php in MacOS. The thing is with my previous installation of MacOS this same script worked like a charm...